# google analytics funnel steps for multi region website?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

Developed the multiple region shopping website, Now creating the goals in google analytic for successful purchase of product,But the question is how we can add the funnel steps in mutiple region site.
like /us/shop and uk/shop that proceed towads the thankyou page of the site which is added as the goal tracking url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use regex to select the correct page name, this also needs to be applied to the destination page.
Take in consideration that the match type selected on the Goal is applied to the filter:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#matchTypes

> There are three diferent match types that define how Analytics identifies a URL for either a goal or a funnel. The match type that you select for your goal URL also applies to the URLs in the funnel, if you create one.

So here is a screenshot of a proposal configuration

[image]

Test the regex and see if this match with you actual page configuration